# Why do I get a "tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format" error when installing hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, tar

Running Mac OS Big Sur 11.5.2 (Apple M1 chip)

When I run the command "curl -sSL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/main/scripts/bootstrap.sh|](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/main/scripts/bootstrap.sh%7C) bash -s", I get :

tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.3.3 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----

Comment: Hyperledger fabric doesn't have builds for the Apple ARM processor, so that's probably why it isn't working. Maybe someone who has got hyperledger fabric working on Apple ARM can provide details on how they did it, either by utilising the x86 builds with rosetta2 or by compiling hyperledger fabric from source for the Apple ARM processor

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that script builds tar file names to download based on your local machine architecture:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/f9027a48cb6028243de75240b6a85f90834edaab/scripts/bootstrap.sh#L12

```
ARCH=$(echo "$(uname -s|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'|sed 's/mingw64_nt.*/windows/')-$(uname -m | sed 's/x86_64/amd64/g')")
```

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/f9027a48cb6028243de75240b6a85f90834edaab/scripts/bootstrap.sh#L162-L163

```
BINARY_FILE=hyperledger-fabric-${ARCH}-${VERSION}.tar.gz
CA_BINARY_FILE=hyperledger-fabric-ca-${ARCH}-${CA_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

And then tries to download them from GitHub:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/f9027a48cb6028243de75240b6a85f90834edaab/scripts/bootstrap.sh#L90

```
download "${BINARY_FILE}" "https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v${VERSION}/${BINARY_FILE}"
```

For me on an older Intel-based Mac, this results in a download URL something like https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.3.3/hyperledger-fabric-darwin-amd64-2.3.3.tar.gz, which does exist. I guess whatever `ARCH` value your M1-based Mac generates results in a tar file URL that does not exist. Maybe you can tweak the script so it downloads the same binaries as my Intel-based Mac and get things working using Rosetta.

Edit: Fabric [v2.5](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v2.5.0) now publishes arm64 binaries and Docker images.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond. I will give that a shot

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with the M1 chip. Well the one line solution to the problem is to 'make' your own binaries and copy them over.

Detail steps follow here:

Step 1 : Clone fabric and fabric-ca

```
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric 
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca
```

Step 2: Change directory to 'fabric'. Make Native files

```
make native
```

Step 3: Move the binaries to respective folder

```
mv build/bin $destination_folder/
mv sampleconfig $destination_folder/config
```

Step 4 : Repeat with fabric-ca

```
cd fabric-ca-client 
make fabric-ca-client
mv bin/fabric-ca-client $destination_folder/bin
```

Step 5: Navigate to your $destination_folder/ and run things as usual.

Note : I learnt about the non support to M1 and also that I've to 'make' my own native files from hyperledger.org.  The full credits of this answer goes to Brett Logan (https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-18389?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true).