# Mac M1 apple chip: Hyperledger Fabric samples download: "2.4.1 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download" Error

Tags: macos, hyperledger-fabric, apple-m1

On my mac M1 computer, Trying to download Fabric binaries and images using following command:

> curl -sSL <URL for Fabric 2.4.1> | bash -s

**Getting the error:**

```
===> Downloading version 2.4.1 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.4.1/hyperledger-fabric-darwin-arm64-2.4.1.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9  100     9    0     0     23      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    23
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.4.1 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, Hyperledger Fabric is not publishing Docker images built for M1 Mac.

- [GitHub issue for native 64-bit ARM support](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/2994)
- [Related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314626/why-do-i-get-a-tar-error-opening-archive-unrecognized-archive-format-error-w)

Edit: Fabric [v2.5](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v2.5.0) publishes arm64 binaries and Docker images.

Answer (score 1):

I forked the fabric-samples repository and updated the docker images to make it work on apple m1 chip.

Feel free to check it out: https://github.com/gpietro/fabric-samples-apple-m1